# Javascript hide menu on outside click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the following html:

```
<div id="otherdiv"></div>
 <div class="overlay">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Val1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Val2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

and JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#otherdiv').on('mouseup', function(e){
     var left  = e.clientX  + "px";
     var top  = e.clientY  + "px";
     var div = $('.overlay');
     div[0].style.left = left;
     div[0].style.top = top;
     $(".overlay").show(200);
   });
 $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.overlay').hide(200);
  });
});
```

I need to hide my `.overlay` when the user clicks somewhere outside it and show it when the user clicks `#otherdiv`. When I attach an event to `document` and click on `otherdiv`, my overlay shows and then immediately hides. How to fix that behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: You can do `on('mouseleave'`

Comment: @iamdevlinph that is for hovering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `document.click` check if the `event.target` is not the `#otherdiv`  or  is not a children of the `#otherdiv` and  `event.target` is not the `.overlay` or its children then hide the `$(".overlay")`.

A sample snippet.Added a css for the `#otherdiv` and `.overlay` for demo>the overlay will be hidden only when the user clicks outside

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#otherdiv').on('mouseup', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     var left  = e.clientX  + "px";
     var top  = e.clientY  + "px";
     var div = $('.overlay');
     div[0].style.left = left;
     div[0].style.top = top;
     $(".overlay").show(200);
   });
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
  
  if( ! $('#otherdiv').is(e.target)&&    $('#otherdiv').has(e.target).length === 0 && !$('.overlay').is(e.target)  && $('.overlay').has(e.target).length === 0 ){
    $('.overlay').hide(200);
  }
   
  });
});
```

```css
#otherdiv{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:#ddd;
}

.overlay{
  
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="otherdiv">
  click here to show
</div>
 <div class="overlay">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Val1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Val2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`click` and `mouseup` events fire at the same time read more about it here - https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html

An interesting thing about how jQuery handles animations is it puts things in the queue - so, your `hide()` animation is queued to run 200ms after `show()`, even though the both functions are firing at the same time.

Instead, I would just suggest using one click event for this -

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if(event.target.id == 'otherdiv' && !$('.overlay').is(":visible")) {
       //do stuff to show
    }
    else if($('.overlay').is(":visible")) {
        $('.overlay').hide(200);
    }
});
```

The first `if` checks to make sure that the element with the id `otherdiv` has been clicked and that the overlay is not currently visible. The next if checks to see if there has been a click and the overlay is visible.